# Polynomials that generate given ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

We define an ideal $I$ to be the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients, with constant and linear terms divisible by $5$. (If $f(x) = a_0+a_1 x + \cdots \in I$, both $a_0$ and $a_1$ are divisible by $5$). I have already shown that $I$ is an ideal in $\mathbb Z[x]$. How do I go about finding polynomials that generate $I$?

Comment: Imitate the method given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616484/prove-that-i-is-a-finitely-generated-ideal-of-mathbbzx-by-finding-a-fin) for the generators. Note that $2$ generators suffice in general, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629484/prove-that-all-ideals-in-mathbbzx-are-generated-by-two-elements).

Comment: Try to find a basis of this ideal as an abelian group and check if some elements of the basis can be linear combinations with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** $$5b_0+5b_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots=5(b_0+b_1x)+x^2(a_2+\cdots).$$
Any guess now?